# Can't test active spring boot Profile

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, profiles

I have spring boot application. I want create two profiles for SecurityConfig: dev, prod. First attempt was with two classes extends from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but than I create two Beans within SecurityConfig class.
My Configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthorizeFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthorizeFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("prod")
    public WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter prod() {
        return new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                //some code...
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter dev() {
        return new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                        //some code...
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
                       //some code...
        };
    }
}
```

Also class for run application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

How can I test that correct profiles is active when I will start application? 
When I add empty test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SecurityConfig.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class SpringProfileConfigurationTest {


    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter securityConfig;

    @Test
    public void testSecurityConfigDevActiveProfile() {

    }

}
```

It is fall down with error:

> ```
>  .NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework
>       .security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter'
>       available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>       Dependency annotations:{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation
>       .Autowired(required=true)}
> ```

**UPD**: add "classes" to @ContextConfiguration, and than another error:

> BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

So the problem now is in org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService - It can't be Autowired. It is used in

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthorizeFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    //some code;
}
```

Comment: can you show your project hierarchy

Comment: @Deadpool what exactly? Project is a little big

Comment: Add the end I separated profile Beans to two different classes and change 


    @Autowired//@Bean
    public JwtAuthorizeFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthorizeFilter();
    }
tests are passed but now another  Autowired Bean JwtTokenUtil is null. It's make me crazy

Comment: can you try this `@ActiveProfiles(SecurityConfig.dev)` on top of `SpringProfileConfigurationTest` class, i believe this should work, with the code that you posted yesterday

Answer (score 0):

In order to add Security Bean to your test, add `SecurityConfig` to your [ContextConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) definition

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SecurityConfig.class})
```